# Angular Universal - OG meta tags not working with child routes

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, meta-tags, angular-universal

My website hosted on http://abc.xyz.com OG meta tag works for the main page.
If I am adding it to the child routes it doesn't work. for example - http://abc.xyz.com/pqr/slug-url.

index.html

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="XYZ" >
<meta property="og:title" content="XYZ" >
<meta property="og:description" content="XYZ" >
<meta property="og:image" content="xyz imagepath" >
<meta property="og:url" content="xyz url" >
```

component.ts

```
 this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:type', content: 'article' });
 this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:site_name', content: 'XYZ' });
 this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:title', content: config.title });
 this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:description', content: config.description });
 this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:image', content: config.image });
 this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:url', content: config.url });
```

server.js

```
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory
}));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', './');
app.use('/', express.static('./', {index: false}));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {
    req
  });
});
```

If I am checking on developer tool, it shows added meta tags but doesn't reflect on Facebook while posting page.

Thanks.

Comment: Is other data on the page (main content, ...) loaded correctly server side?

Comment: yes. the page renders on the server side. the only difference is main URL working. and not working for child routes.

Comment: Sorry, but I meant: for child routes, is the content loaded correctly (apart from the meta tags) ? I'm trying to understand if it's a problem with just your meta implementation, or universal in general

Comment: yes. content loading properly and showing on browser correctly. it just issue with meta tags

Comment: You probably have to debug the call chain to check if your updateMeta code is called, for a start. Sorry, can't think of anything else without seeing the code

Comment: I already debugged and tags are added properly

Comment: If tags are added properly, what is the problem then? i'm talking about debugging the server-side rendering. Your issue is that if you look at the source for page http://abc.xyz.com/pqr/slug-url, then there is no meta, right ? I'm talking about viewing source code of the page (ctrl+U), not inspecting elements

Comment: yes, you are correct.viewing the source code of page shows tags are not updated but in case of inspect element shows updated. it happens only for child routes - abc.xyz.com/pqr/slug-url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164877/discussion-between-nilesh-mistry-and-david).